# Handling Uncertainty with Budget Constraints in Robust Optimization

Tags: optimization, stochastic-processes, operations-research, python

Let's say I  have a linear optimization problem with some uncertain parameters

#### Case 1: Uncertain Parameters are present independently in *different* constraints

$$maximize\ x_1+x_2$$
$$ax_1+bx_2\leq 6 $$
$$x_1,x_2\geq 0$$
$$\bar{a}=3, \bar{b}=5$$
where a & b are uncertain parameter $a\in [1.5,4.5 ]$($\pm 1.5$ from mean) and $b\in [3,7 ]$ ($\pm 2$ from mean).
I solved this using the robust optimization approach as given in [this article](http://blog.yhat.com/posts/decision-marking-under-uncertainty-2.html). 
Robust counterpart of above equation can be written as below.

$$maximize\ x_1+x_2$$
$$3x_1+5x_2+\Gamma z+ p_1 +p_2 \leq 6$$
$$z+p_1\geq 1.5y_1$$
$$z+p_2\geq 2y_2$$
$$y_1\geq x_1$$
$$y_2\geq x_2$$
$$z,x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2,p_1,p_2 \geq 0$$
Here $\Gamma$ is budget of uncertainty, $\Gamma \in [0,2]$ , upper limit of $\Gamma$ is maximum no of uncertain parameter.

#### Case2: Uncertain Parameter is being shared in multiple constraints

I solved above using simple Linear programming problem. But I am stuck when uncertain parameter is being shared across multiple constraints. For example
$$maximize\ x_1+x_2$$
$$ax_1+bx_2\leq 6 $$
$$x_1 \geq b+1$$
$$x_1,x_2\geq 0$$
$$\bar{a}=3, \bar{b}=5$$
where a & b are uncertain parameter $a\in [1.5,4.5 ]$($\pm 1.5$ from mean) and $b\in [3,7 ]$ ($\pm 2$ from mean).

#### Case 3: Uncertain Parameters are being multiplied

In another case when uncertain parameters are being multiplied to each other, for example
$$maximize\ x_1+x_2$$
$$ax_1+abx_2\leq 6 $$
$$x_1 \geq b+1$$
$$x_1,x_2\geq 0$$
$$\bar{a}=3, \bar{b}=5$$
where a & b are uncertain parameter $a\in [1.5,4.5 ]$($\pm 1.5$ from mean) and $b\in [3,7 ]$ ($\pm 2$ from mean).

**What would be mathematical robust counterpart for case 2 and case 3?**

Answer (score 0):

I face the same question (for case 2) now. Could you please tell me whether you have addressed this problem?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/2094887)